# Raspberry pi3 Serial communication not working

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have a call monitoring system on raspberry pi. which is working fine on raspberry pi 2. But pi3 it is not transmitting data on serial port. my simple program is

```
import serial
port=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=10417,timeout=.05)
address=1
port.write(chr(address))
```

it could not receive data. there may be some configuration problem. i edited /boot/cmdline.txt file

```
sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
```

removed console=ttyserial1,115200 kgdboc=ttyserial1,115200.

but I didn't get /etc/inittab file to comment out T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

added at the last of the page

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
enable_uart=1
```

to disable bluetooth modem

```
sudo systemctl disable hciuart
```

what configuration i have to do more to receive data from serial port??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already did the usual set up for the serial port, as you had it working on a pi2 before, then it could just be the case that as
the raspberry pi 3 has changed things around a bit, ttyAMA0 now refers to the serial port that is connected to the bluetooth. The old serial port is now called ttyS0. So if you have an RPI3, everywhere you see "ttyAMA0" below, you should read "ttyS0".

So......

```
import serial
port=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0",baudrate=10417,timeout=.05)
address=1
port.write(chr(address))
```

Comment: By using S0 instead of AMA0 control exit from infinite loop. but no valid data is transmit or receive. is there any other setting for s0 ?or other setting related to pi3??

Comment: Dear @user007, did you solve infinite loop problem on ttyAMA0, because right now, I have the same issue cannot read any thing on it.